# double.ToString(0.55, {en-US}) returns .55 - C#

Tags: c#, string, double, cultureinfo, string-conversion

I have a `method` which `returns` a `string`.

In case 1 - `return doubleVariable.ToString("0.55", {en-US})` returns `0.55` `// **I need 0.55**`

In case 2 - `return doubleVariable.ToString("0.00", {en-US})` returns an `empty string` `// **I need 0.00**`

Any hints how to get rid of this?

EDIT:

**METHOD**

```
private string GetContent(
            NumericUserVariable templateNumericUserVariable,
            double doubleValue,
            CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {

            string placeholder = "#";
            if (!templateNumericUserVariable.IsDecimal)
            {
                return doubleValue.ToString();
            }

            string decimalPlaces = placeholder;

            if (templateNumericUserVariable.DecimalPlace > 0)
            {
                decimalPlaces = decimalPlaces.PadRight(

                    // templateNumericUserVariable.DecimalPlace - 1,
                    templateNumericUserVariable.DecimalPlace, '#');

                return doubleValue.ToString(placeholder + "." + decimalPlaces, cultureInfo);
            }

            return doubleValue.ToString(placeholder, cultureInfo);
        }
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Can you provide short but complete sample demonstrating the problem.

Comment: If I replace `{en-US}` (which won't compile) with `CultureInfo.GetCulture("en-US")` it doesn't return an empty string, it returns `0.00`, so please post some *actual* code that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Please tell what the value of `doubleVariable` is in each case. What does `doubleVariable.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-US"))` with no format string return in each case? **Edit:** Your code looks confusing, but you are using `#` characters instead of `0` in your format strings. You might want to change that.

Comment: The value of doubleVariable can be any double number with 2 decimal places. It is entered by the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reach your objective you need to change the `#` character with a `0`

0 means, place a number in this position also if it is a zero value

```
doubleVariable.ToString("0.00", cultureInfo);
```

You can read about [Custom Numeric Format here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> "0" - Zero placeholder   Replaces the zero with the corresponding
>   digit if one is present; otherwise, zero appears in the result string.

Instead for the `#` character you could read

> "#" - Digit placeholder   Replaces the "#" symbol with the
>   corresponding digit if one is present; otherwise, no digit appears in
>   the result string.

Comment: The second parameter to the ToString() method is not hard-coded to {en-US}. It takes a different value out of 4 values provided by the client. Can directly having CultureInfo.InvariantCulture help me?

Comment: This works. But, returns 0.0 for 0.00. How to get 0.00?

Answer (score 1):

OK, so you are really complaining that `(0.0).ToString("#.##")` returns `""`, right?

Try `(0.0).ToString("0.00")` instead.

Here `(0.0)` is the value of your `doubleVariable`.

But also consider:

```
doubleValue.ToString("F" + templateNumericUserVariable.DecimalPlace, cultureInfo)
```

for example `(0.0).ToString("F2")` gives `"0.00"` with two (fixed) decimals.